# Update the first row of two columns in SQL table

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm new to C# SQL. What im trying is to update existing Rows in my CurrencyRates Table which

has 2 columns buyEURrate and sellEURrate with type float.

on button click i want to change its values of its first rows

im getting the new data from 2 textboxes "EURbuyRate" and EURsellRate"

dont really know the syntax for it

```
var insertSQL = "UPDATE CurrencyRates (buyEURrate, sellEURrate) VALUES (@buyEURrate, @sellEURrate)";


        string connectionString = @"Data Source=C:\Users\FluksikartoN\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\BuroFoki\BuroFoki\MainDB.sdf";

        using (var cn = new SqlCeConnection(connectionString))
        using (var cmd = new SqlCeCommand(insertSQL, cn))
        {
            cn.Open();

           cmd.Parameters.Add("buyEURrate", SqlDbType.Float);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("sellEURrate", SqlDbType.Float);

            cmd.Parameters["buyEURrate"].Value =  float.Parse(EURbuyRate.Text.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters["sellEURrate"].Value = float.Parse(EURsellRate.Text.ToString());

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
```

On button click for update "SqlCeException was unhandeled 
System error "

Comment: An UPDATE query needs a WHERE clause unless you want to change every row on your database. The WHERE clause allows you to identify which row should be updated using the PrimaryKey of your table or other UNIQUE index present. Please add the schema of your table

Comment: sorry its not SQL-server i edited the columns in the table are just for 1 row so this table needs only one row for each columns can you shot an example of implementation

Comment: set the cmd.CommandType as well also do a simple google search there are `1000's` of working examples here on stackoverflow as well as the internet.. used parmeterized query's `@` specifically you need to know how to declare / pass params as well.. wrap your code around a try catch as well .. don't assume that it will always work / have no errors

Comment: searched some google but it seems what i want is very unusual

and editted to see my code 

Sorry im really new to SQL

Answer (score 0):

From your posted code looks like you are using `UPDATE` statement like

```
UPDATE CurrencyRates (buyEURrate, sellEURrate) VALUES (buyEURrate, sellEURrate);
```

That syntax is for `INSERT` and not `UPDATE`. Your SQL statement should looks like

```
UPDATE CurrencyRates SET buyEURrate = buyEURrate, 
sellEURrate = sellEURrate 
WHERE some_condition;
```